# Increasing pagination in Silverstripe admin

Tags: php, silverstripe

I'm using Silverstripe 3.1. The site will have hundreds of users and lots of files / assets.

How can I increase the number of items listed to (from 15 to 50 or so per page) in the admin for both users and files.

Even better if I can just set it by default for all areas of the admin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it manually by overloading getCMSFields() and using method `$field->setItemsPerPage(50)` on grid paginator field.

The other option is to use yaml file. You need create config.yml and put it in _config directory then put in your yaml file:

```
GridFieldPaginator:
    itemsPerPage: 50
```

Check also these links:

- https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.1/developer_guides/forms/field_types/gridfield
- https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.2/developer_guides/configuration/configuration/

Comment: Fab thanks.. I've added it to the yaml file... 

What about the files list?

Comment: Check what component is responsible for this and do the same. If you read configuration link that I gave you link to then you'd know that you can set any property from any class using convention as above.

Comment: It took me quite a while to find but I got it... 

AssetAdmin:
    page_length: 50

/dev/build is then needed of course.

Add that to your answer I'll accept it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm afraid I've got one that I can't work out how to set..

In framework/forms/UploadField.php it has the line below, which is not effected by the above. Obvioulsy I don't want to edit UploadField.php so how would I add that? 

  $config->addComponent(new GridFieldPaginator(8));

Comment: Uploadfield is not responsible for showing results on grid but for uploading files, I don't understand your question.

Comment: It's used when you select From files to select files that have already been uploaded. In this case selecting images from a gallery folder. There are about 80 image and only 8 are displayed at a time. Changing $config->addComponent(new GridFieldPaginator(8)); to $config->addComponent(new GridFieldPaginator(20)); works but obviously is bad practice.